# Sitecore image browser throws exception on null parameter

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

```cs
public static void BrowseImage(string id, string root, bool ignoreSpeak)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) id, "id");
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) root, "root");
  MediaBrowserOptions mediaBrowserOptions = new MediaBrowserOptions();
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(root))
    root = "/sitecore/media library";
  mediaBrowserOptions.IgnoreSpeak = ignoreSpeak;
  mediaBrowserOptions.Root = Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem(root);
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    mediaBrowserOptions.SelectedItem = Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem(id);
  SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(mediaBrowserOptions.ToUrlString().ToString(), "1200px", "700px", string.Empty, true);
}
```

Getting an exception when trying to open the file browser/ `BrowseImage` dialog. Stacktrace is showing that the exception is happening inside of the `BrowseImage` method inside of `Sitecore.Kernel` on line 8 of the above snippet. When it gets to that line, it tries to set `IgnoreSpeak` to `True` which then triggers an assertion on the parameter name `Value` with a null parameter.

This results in an error message that appears on the user's screen when they try to open the file picker/browse media dialog on any field that requires you to pick a media item from the media library/content area.

Any reason why this should be happening? Why would any assertions be triggered when setting a simple bool value?

Full stack trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +63
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dialogs.BrowseImage(String id, String root, Boolean ignoreSpeak) +154
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.File.OpenFile(ClientPipelineArgs args) +632

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +313
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +176
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines() +503
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +779
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +110
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2994
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: @MarekMusielak added to my original post.

Comment: Looking at your code I'm almost sure that the exception is thrown when you try to set `mediaBrowserOptions.Root` value. Check what it the `Client.ContentDatabase` and if `Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem(root)` is  not null.

Comment: @MarekMusielak this is actually code decompiled from `Sitecore.Kernel`. That `BrowseImage` method is not mine. But I will try your suggestion and get back to you.